# fahrenheit to celsius function is not running

Tags: javascript, html

Java script function is not running properly. I invoked a function tends to convert fahrenheit to celsius.
the im not able to get value from text box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jQuery/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="demo"> </p>
        <script>
            function toCelsius(f) {
                return (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
            }

            
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius(document.getElementById("temp").value);
        </script>
        <form onsubmit="toCelsius()" action="">
        <input type="text" id="temp">
        <input type="submit" id="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're running the script before the elements are rendered on the page. Try placing the script before your `</body>` tag. Also. Part of the script is outside the curly braces?

Comment: a garbage value is displayed but not working prperly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load completely the DOM tree to use the elements. When you are writting inside of `#demo` , the form is not rendered yet.
To solve this you can attach javascript to a dom content loaded event, or move it in the bottom of the code:

```
    <p id="demo"> </p>
    <form onsubmit="makeSubmit()">
    <input type="text" id="temp">
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
    </form>
    <script>
        function toCelsius(f) {
            return (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
        }

        function makeSubmit() {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius(document.getElementById("temp").value);
             return false; //needs to prevent submit form
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to use a `form` to use your javascript functions.
Here is how I did it:

**Javascript:**

```
function toCelsius(f) {
    return (5 / 9) * (f - 32);
}

function convert() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius(document.getElementById("temp").value);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<input type="text" id="temp" />
<input type="button" id="submit" value="Convert" onclick="convert()" />
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/a7wszebf/)

Comment: It works, but the problem is not in the submit event, is in the order of javascript inclusion in the DOM. In your fiddle works because jsfiddle rearrange js when DOM is complete loaded.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude The order of the javascript is still correct. It form-submit was the issue. I just tested it out locally, but had to replace the js code with the fixed one and change the submit button to trigger the `convert` function. You may try it locally if you wish to test.

Comment: No, the problem was in this line `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = toCelsius(document.getElementById("temp").value);`, when this line is executed, the `document.getElementById("temp")` is undefined because the DOM is not completely loaded. In the submit event, user missing the prevention of default action with a return false for example, but it was not the problem. Sure. Test it without your changes. P.D. Note that I was not downvote you, I am only commenting.